# Generics - type inference and type erasure

Tags: java, generics, types, type-inference, type-erasure

This code compiled with Java SE-1.7 gives following output (below). I understand, the inferred type of value should be Object, how does it come that there are String and Integer Types recognized?

```
public class Generics1 {

    public class Pocket<T>{
      public T value;
      public void set( T value ) { this.value = value; }
      public void set( String value ) { this.value = (T)value; } //warning
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pocket<Object> intPocket =  new Generics1().new Pocket<>();

        intPocket.set("foo");
        System.out.println(intPocket.value);
        System.out.println(intPocket.value.getClass().getName());

        intPocket.set(12);
        System.out.println(intPocket.value);
        System.out.println(intPocket.value.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo
java.lang.String
12
java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 2):

`value.getClass()` returns the runtime type of the object that `value` refers to.

An `Integer` stored in a field of type `Object` is still an `Integer`.

Comment: It should be noted that `12` can be an `Integer` literal.

Comment: @Turing85: The literal is not relevant at all.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `public T value` has its type erased, so it is essentially `public Object value`. But even if your *variable* doesn't specify the exact type, the *instance* itself still knows what class it is.

E.g.

```
Object value = "bananas";
System.out.println(value.getClass().getName());
```

Output:

```
java.lang.String
```